# Is there a way to see completed process list in mysql (SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST)

Tags: mysql

I am new to Mysql server, I use the below query to see what are all processes or queries that users are currently executing.

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

I needed to check those processes, which users executed in past. like those processes which were executed and they got completed or aborted.

Is there a way to check the already executed processes via any query in MysqL server ?

Comment: I think you are going to have to process the logs to get this info, assuming you have the right onces turned on

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help with questions on database internals like this one.

Comment: @Shadow I disagree here. SQL queries are also programing, or else every single SQL question would be on DBA site, right ?

Comment: @MarcAlff this is not about sql queries. This is about logging and configuration of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, queries executes in the past can be seen in the general log.

See the reference manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: Marc Alff, Thanks for the reference, after reading this post, I guess its not as straightforward as listing full processlist. For now I shall accept your post as answer and close this question.

Comment: BUT... You had to have the general log turned on!